# Oracle SqlDeveloper - Translate TSQL to PLSQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

Oracle documentation for SqlDeveloper talks about a command line interface to perform different operations. I am interested in migration utility and translate action.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/intro.htm#RPTUG46002

When I try to run the below command to translate a MS SqlServer (TSQL) to Oracle (PLSQL). I always get an error. However, I am able to translate just fine using Tools > Migration > Scratch Editor.

**Command:**

```
sdcli migration -actions=translate -file=D:\Sdcli\Input\One.sql 
-translator=sqlserver -output=D:\Sdcli
```

One.sql file contains

```
select * from someTable
```

**Output:**

Error:null
capture, convert, datamove, delcaptured, delconn, delconverted, driver, generate, guide, idmap, info, init, lscaptured, lsconn, lsconverted, mkconn, qm, runsql, scan and translate

Note: I have tested with various permission levels so lack of permission is not the issue.

Please Help !!

Comment: Trying with 'select top 100 * from someTable' in One.sql file also gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the report_translator.txt and the log files in the log folder under your output directory? Can you provide the content of them?

If you don't find the output directory then it is a permission problem so the sdcli doesn't have the right to create the output folder.